# Why is the existential quantifier in the consequent of the Axiom Schema of Replacement not "unique"?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

In Kenneth Kunen's, *"The Foundations of Mathematics"*, the **Axiom Schema of Replacement** is written as so:

> $(1) \ \ \ \  \forall A \big ( \forall x \in A \exists ! y \ \varphi(x,y) \rightarrow \exists B \forall x \in A \ \color{blue}{\exists y} \in B \ \varphi(x,y) \big)$

I've gone through a few exercises and, at least to this point, it seems peculiar to me that the axiom is not written as:

$$ (2) \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall A \big ( \forall x \in A \exists ! y \ \varphi(x,y) \rightarrow \exists B \forall x \in A \ \color{red}{\exists ! y} \in B \ \varphi(x,y) \big)$$

---

Looking at the internal formula  (relative the universal quantifier over $A$) of the traditional definition $(1)$:

$$ \forall x \in A \exists ! y \ \varphi(x,y) \rightarrow \exists B \forall x \in A \ \exists y \in B \ \varphi(x,y) $$

If the antecedent is true, then it must necessarily be the case that there exists an unique $y \in B$ that, for a given $x$, satisfies a $\varphi(x,y)$ (otherwise, we would arrive at a contradiction).

So why exactly is $(2)$ not used as the Axiom Schema of Replacement? I understand that $(1)$ is perfectly valid...but why is it preferred over $(2)$?

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Thanks~

Comment: No real reason whatsoever - it's one symbol shorter.

Comment: Oh. Really? lol. Fair enough! Cheers~

Comment: It's worth noting that a lot of axioms in Kunen are stated in a weaker form than their usual statement, though together they all amount to the exact same thing. I think he was trying to be a bit minimalist?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine yes. For example, his axiom of pairing reads differently than what one would find on Wikipedia.

Comment: @NoahSchweber . I would describe Kunen's style as super-compact.